# Converting my website into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple html pages that i want to convert into a WordPress website.  I've installed WordPress and created the necessary files. So far i've been looking for a tutorial on how to convert a static website to WordPress but with no luck. Most of the tutorials the user doesn't have knowledge of html or php and as i understand WordPress has functions you have to add to your html page.  Here is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/code.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php
include "header.php";
?>
<div id="main">
        <div class='nav'><a href="about.php">About</a></div>
        <div class='nav'><a>Events</a></div>
        <div class='nav'><a href="venues.php">Venues</a></div>
        <div class='nav'><a>Gallery</a></div>
        <div class='nav'><a href="arts.php">Arts</a></div>
        <div class='nav'><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></div>
    </div>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to convert this into WordPress, so it's easy for a user to add and edit content from WordPress admin panel.  Is there any tutorial any of you can recommend that walks me through how to do this?  If not, how would you add WordPress functions into my index.php to make it compatible with WordPress.

Comment: its not that simply, you need funcktions like the_content(). Bestway you take a simply theme search for some on the internet then try to modify it

Comment: Lots of learning ahead of you - the good news is that it's not that hard and it is all well documented.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is a completely different beast from a basic static site. All the content is database-driven, which means all your 'html pages' need to be converted to Wordpress pages through the dashboard. Converting won't be a quick process unless your site is very small.

Give each page a sensible title and 'slug' and cut and paste your existing code into the text editor (you'll find plenty of help for this online). Converting images will be more of a hassle - they need to be loaded in via WP media. Links will also need to be changed.

To make sure your site has a static front page (i.e. not a blog) go to Settings...Reading... and click the link.

Styling the content is done through page templates, which come in packages called themes. Use one of the default themes until your content is transferred. They'll even have menus and allow you to modify some styles and header images etc. Have a look at the files in an existing theme to see how it all works.

When you're ready to style, either use one of these themes as a starting point or if you want to start from scratch do a bit of research into blank or starter themes - there's a ton out there. Then I suggest you follow a tutorial on designing a WP theme...

Answer (score 0):

If your site is simple, try taking a barebones/starter WordPress theme and customizing it to use your stylesheets/javascript etc.

This will be much easier and robust than creating something from scratch.

There are also tools like [Theme Matcher](http://themematcher.com) which will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's about the simplest barebones super basic explanation I could come up with..

When writing a Wordpress website I think the first thing you should get is that where-as coding a plain HTML site you have to write the structure of the page and the content.. when you write a Wordpress page you are only writing the structure, all of the content is going to be created in the Wordpress backend user portal.

So to start, remove all the content from your code and your left with this (I'm going to remove the PHP includes and start fresh)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Include stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
        <!-- Include scripts -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/code.js"></script>

        <!-- Page title / meta -->
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Page container -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <!-- Nav -->
            <div class="nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

A wordpress theme is made up of several PHP files and whenever a theme is displayed, typically the index.php file is loaded first so that's where we'll start.

Wordpress themes, most of them, amongst all the PHP files that make up the theme, there will be a header.php file, footer.php file..

So in index.php the first line we write is get_header(); (within php tags of course)  This is a Wordpress function that is essentially

I assume your going to want your nav on all pages so you can cut all of this code out of your index file and paste it into header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Include stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
        <!-- Include scripts -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/code.js"></script>

        <!-- Page title / meta -->
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Page container -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <!-- Nav -->
            <div class="nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Back to index.php the second line we'll add is get_footer();  another Wordpress function to get footer.php.

Currently index.php would look like this now..

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

because everything else is in header.php.. well that closing body and html tag.. those go in footer.php. so your index.php file is going to end up looking like this

```
<?php get_header();
get_footer(); ?>
```

---

Header.php is going to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html  <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <!-- Page title / meta -->
        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Page container -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <!-- Nav -->
            <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and you know what's in footer.php.  As far as those CSS and javascript files, those are going to be in your functions.php file.

Wordpress has LOTS and LOTS of prefab functions that they like for you to use and it would take forever to explain them all.  Luckily a lot of that's already been done in the [Wordpress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/) Though it's got a lot to be desired as far as the quality of the documentation in some places in my opinion it is something you should spend a good amount of time reading thru before you start, in order to familiarize yourself with all their functions.